# jquery form submit with .on()

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to send a form created by jquery.
The form is appended to a div and variable 'data' below is created using php, I'll just post the most important js code.

I tried many things with and without 'on()' but I fail in getting the alert box displaying the '1' so that I know the code block is actually executed..tbh I don't get what I'm doing wrong, any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
$(".r5").click(function(event){
    var data='<select name="sForum"><option value="1">bla</option></select>';
    $(this).parent().next('div').html('<form class="moveform">'+data+'<input type="submit" name="submit" class="movethisform" value="Move Thread" /></form>');
});
$("form.moveform").on("submit",function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: At the moment you are trying to bind the event handler to `form.moveform`, the form does not exist yet. Either use event delegation or bind the handler when the form was added to the DOM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are binding to the form before it exists. Bind the event to the document, and pass the form selector to `.on`:

```
$(".r5").click(function(event){
    var data='<select name="sForum"><option value="1">bla</option></select>';
    $(this).parent().next('div').html('<form class="moveform">'+data+'<input type="submit" name="submit" class="movethisform" value="Move Thread" /></form>');
});
$(document).on("submit", "form.moveform", function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$("inout.movethisform").on("click",function(event){
    alert(1);
    $("form.moveform").submit();
});
```

Comment: Where should this code go? What's wrong with using a submit event handlers? Why should this solve the issue?

Comment: The purpose of replacing .live with .on is to bind a selector in a parent selector. That's why you should not coding in this way anymore when using .on